# Insert into filterSelections: [String: Any]

Tags: swift

I have a string: Any array, like this

```
public var filterSelections: [String: Any] = [
    "myFilter": ["all"],
    //"fromDate": Date = Date()
    //"searchByName": String = ""
]
```

I would like to add value "sampleFilterValue" to the default value "all", so the array looks like this.

```
[
  "myFilter": ["all", "sampleFilterValue"]
]
```

Comment: `if var filters = filterSelections["myFilter"] as? [String] { filters.append("sampleFilterValue"); filterSelections["myFilter"] = filters }` ?

Comment: You should avoid using dictionaries with heterogeneous value types. Use a struct or a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if var res = filterSelections["myFilter"] as? [String] { 
   res.append("sampleFilterValue")
   filterSelections["myFilter"] = res
}
```